# capistrano rails 3 git error - fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, git, capistrano

I dont use git, but after upgrading to ruby 1.9.3 and rails 3.017 and using cap to deploy, I get these errors all over the place:

```
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

They don't seem to break anything, but they are annoying. I dont use git, how do I make these go away?

More information (here is what I see)

```
$ cap pirmtlddemo deploy:long  
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
* executing `pirmtlddemo'
* executing `deploy:long'
** transaction: start
* executing `deploy:update_code'
```

Note, I had similar warnings when trying to run localy (rails s) that I got rid of by doing a "git init"

thanks
Joel

Comment: Can you show the error in context?  I wonder if this is really a capistrano error or somewhere else in the deploy.

Comment: I dont necessarily think its a cap problem, but wanted to include all the info. I will update.

Comment: strange - that looks like it is not cap but in your shell - do you have any wrappers or anything?

Comment: what happens when you run: cap invoke COMMAND=hostname

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19492/discussion-between-michael-and-joelio)

Comment: Have you checked if in your deploy script the scm is set to none and deploy_via is set to something that doesn't use a scm, eg. copy

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured this out, it looks like several gems including clearance, gvis, jquery-rails, vestal_versions have included in their gemspec's a dependency on git, see https://github.com/thoughtbot/clearance/blob/master/clearance.gemspec#L17. I am not sure why they do this, seems like an unnecessary dependency...